Expansion of $\mathbb{E}(|X|)$ and $\mathbb{E}(|X|+|Y|)$
Given a numerical-valued random variables $X$ and $Y$, I'm a bit confused about the expansions of $\mathbb{E}(|X|)$ and $\mathbb{E}(|X| + |Y|)$.
For $\mathbb{E}(|X|)$, is it
$$\mathbb{E}(|X|)= \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{|X_1|+|X_2|+...|X_n|}{n}$$
or
$$\mathbb{E}(|X|)= \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{|X_1+X_2+...X_n|}{n}?$$
Similarly, for $\mathbb{E}(|X| + |Y|)$, is it
$$\mathbb{E}(|X| + |Y|)=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{|X_1|+|X_2|+...|X_n|+|Y_1|+...|Y_n|}{n}$$
or
$$\mathbb{E}(|X| + |Y|)=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{|X_1+X_2+...X_n|+|Y_1+...Y_n|}{n}?$$

In both cases, it is the first of the pair. You are considering random variables $|X|$ and $|Y|$, so you take them (not $X$ and $Y$) as basic units of analysis.

The second part of your title also does not match the body of your question: the title says $\mathbb{E}(|X+Y|)$, the body of the question says $\mathbb{E}(|X|+|Y|)$.

Are you sure? E.g., mean(abs(rnorm(1e7))); sqrt(2/pi);abs(mean(rnorm(1e7))) & https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folded_normal_distribution

@ChristophHanck, what do you mean exactly?

@RichardHardy My apologies. I didn't include $\mathbb{E}(|X+Y|)$ because the answer to what $\mathbb{E}(|X|)$ is would already imply what $\mathbb{E}(|X+Y|)$ is.

@whuber, absolutely, I have mistyped in a major way! Of course the first one is the right one!

This is what I meant :-)!

@RichardHardy Just a clarification, the RHS of each equation is the estimator of the LHS part right?

@Fiodor1234, I suppose it could be if we had infinite data, but we do not. Also, if it were, it would imply the estimator equals the true quantity because we have an equality sign there.
